# Resources for learning memory model and Thread safety in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have been searching for resources to understand thread safety in java and came across [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html). Is there any popular/comprehensive resource or books that explains thread safety in a more simpler way, perhaps with more sample programs. I found the above resource hard to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237980/java-5-concurrency-book-recommendations

Comment: You should accept an answer, probably @duffymo's despite this being a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is the best book on multi-threading with Java that I know of.